# capacity of filesystem with bad blocks

Tags: filesystems, badblocks

this is the number of bad blocks:

```
sudo dumpe2fs -b /dev/sda
dumpe2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
113223162
```

this is the number of total blocks:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda | grep -i 'block count'
Block count: 122096646
```

```
Inode count:              30531584
Block count:              122096646
Reserved block count:     6104832
Overhead clusters:        2197334
Free blocks:              119899304
Free inodes:              30531573
```

i'm reading this as 93% of the blocks being bad (113223162 / 122096646)

but when i mount the filesystem, it says that the size is 458Gib (it's listed as a 500Gb drive) with 438G free.  Shouldn't it show something more along the lines of 50Gb free?

Comment: I think `-b` lists the individual block offsets, not the total number of blocks, so there is 1 bad block.